# ruby on rails jqgrid

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, jqgrid

I am working with a rails app. and I am using jqgrid for my html responces. I need to export selected rows (using checkboxes displayed in grid). I used rails fastercsv lib to extract data in .csv but it is exporting all the rows which is displayed on the page. How can I make use of the checkboxes available on the grid to export only selected rows??

I am new to rails and jqgrid so any reply would be appreciated.

Thanx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://github.com/kumarsaurabh20/nextGenBiosensors/blob/master/app/views/oligo_sequences/index.html.erb#L26

from line 24-44. Need to make async:false means synchronous ajax call is the solution.

Answer (score 1):

This is how you can get the selected rows from jqgrid.

```
var selRowIds = grid.jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selarrrow');
           if(selRowIds.length>0)
           {
           for( var i=0;i<selRowIds.length;i++){

           var Name=getCellValue(selRowIds[i],'Name');
           var Company=getCellValue(selRowIds[i],'Company');
$.ajax({
           type: 'POST',
           url: '@Url.Action("ExportToCSV")',
           contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
           data:JSON.stringify({Name:Name,Company:Company}),
           dataType: "json",
          success:function(){
                   grid.trigger("reloadGrid");
            }


               });
}
}
```

Now i'll explain how this code works. I'm using multiselect:true in my jqgrid parameters so i can get my checkboxes with each row. Now if i check 5 rows, they will be selected and i can get their row ids using selarrow, like the way I'm doing in my code and then lets suppose you have Name and Company in your jqgrid columns then i can get their values like i'm doing in my code and then you can make ajax request using jquery to server method(exportToCSV) which in your case will be in ruby-rails.